# Cannot fill a table with passed data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a route like this:

```
Route::get('/userlist', function () {
    $users = User::where('owner_id',Auth::user()->owner_id)->orderBy('created_at','desc');
    return View::make('auth.forms.userlist')->with('user',$users);
});
```

And this is the table that should be filled:

```
...{{$i = 1}}
@foreach($user as $users)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $i }}</td>
        <td>{{$users->salutation}}</td>
        <td>{{$users->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$users->surname}}</td>
        <td>{{$users->email}}</td>
        @if($users->role=="owner")
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="role" checke="1" disabled></td>
        @elseif($users->role == "admin")
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="role" checked="1"></td>
        @else
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="role"></td>
        @endif
        @if($users->role=="owner")
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="release" checked="1" disabled></td>
        @elseif($users->active == true)
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="release" checked="1"></td>
        @else
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="release"></td>
        @endif
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            </tr>
            {{$i++}}
        @endforeach...
```

The table loads and I get no error. I simply get an empty table. Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried to `dd($users)` ? i wonder if your `User::where('owner_id',Auth::user()->owner_id)` actually fetch data or not..

Comment: Technically your code is correct, but please fix your code, when your pass the variable ```users``` you must name the variable also ```users```, why do you name it ```user``` (singular)?
Then in your foreach ```@foreach($users as $user)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `@foreach($users as $user)`.

If you get empty table, `$users` collection is empty, because this code doesn't find any users, it returns Query Builder:

```
$users = User::where('owner_id',Auth::user()->owner_id)->orderBy('created_at','desc');
```

You need to use one of these methods to get collection, object or some value: `->first()`, `->get()`, `->count()`, `->paginate()` etc at the end.

You can check result with `dd($users);` clause in controller or with `{{ dd($users) }}` in a view.

Comment: dang, did not see that `$users` and `$user` swapped place.. although think at least php (with proper error reporting config) will throw some error if it tries to iterate non-existent reference..

Comment: My query is in fact empty but I don't see any error here. This is why I am asking the question. Fixed the $user thing but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the function get() at the end to retrieve the data.

```
$users = User::where('owner_id',Auth::user()->owner_id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```